# Failed prop type: Invalid prop `value` of type `number`

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, hook, textinput

I have an issue with TextInput in react native so when I submit to update, I am getting an error of ' Invalid prop value of type number supplied to ForwardRef(TextInput)'. May someone help me to solve this issue.

Error:

> Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `value` of type `number`
> supplied to `ForwardRef(TextInput)`, expected `string`. at
> node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:173:8 in
> registerError

Here is my code :

```
const [Phase, setPhase] = useState('')
      const [Days, setDay] = useState(null)
      const [TempMin, setTempMin] = useState(null)

  <TextInput
                    style={styles.input}
                    onChangeText={(text) => setPhase(text)}
                    placeholder={plants.Phase}
                    value={Phase}
                    name="Phase"
                    selectTextOnFocus={false}
                    editable={false}


                />
                <Text style={styles.titleInput}>Nombre de jour</Text>
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.input}
                    onChangeText={(text) => setDay(text)}
                    keyboardType='numeric'
                    placeholder={`${plants.Days}`}
                    value={Days}
                    name="Days"
                />
                <Text style={styles.titleInput}>T° Min</Text>
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.input}
                    onChangeText={(text) => setTempMin(text)}
                    keyboardType='numeric'
                    placeholder={`${plants.TempMin}`}
                    value={TempMin}
                    name="TempMin"
                />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`value={String(Days)}`

or

`if(String(Days)){....}`